# Return partial value of field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a good way to achieve this in Elasticsearch :
I have a field "description" which is very long, when I search a word present in this descrption, I would like ES to return something like this : "... before searched word **searched word** after searched world..." instead of all the field description

Example :
description contains : "It is a very beautiful day to go for a walk"
If I searh day, I would like ES to return : "...beautiful **day** to go..."

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want but can help you to find a solution for your case.

[Elasticsearch Highlight](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/highlighting.html)

Here is an example:

```
PUT test_highligh/_doc/1
{
  "description": "It is a very beautiful day to go for a walk"
}

GET /test_highligh/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description": "day"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "description": {
        "pre_tags": ["..."],
        "post_tags": ["..."],
         "fragment_size" : 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> fragment_size The size of the highlighted fragment in characters.
> Defaults to 100.

OUTPUT:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "test_highligh",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 0.2876821,
    "_source": {
      "description": "It is a very beautiful day to go for a walk"
    },
    "highlight": {
      "description": [
        "beautiful ...day..."
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

[image]